# storage size not constant when using offsetof and including termios.h with android ndk

Tags: c, compiler-errors, android-ndk, termios

I encounter a strange error when compiling this

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stddef.h>
struct Test {
    int a;
    int b;
};
void test() {
    static int test_array[(offsetof(struct Test,a)) > 0 ? 2 : 1];
}
```

with arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -c:

```
test.c:8:13: error: storage size of 'test_array' isn't constant
```

The strange thing about this is, when I remove the

```
#include <termios.h>
```

the whole thing compiles without error. Also, when I use the gcc installed on my ubuntu system, it does not complain independent of including termios.h.
Ayone any Idea why?

Background: I am trying to compile a ghc (glasgow haskell compiler) android crosscompiler, and hs2hsc fails on this situation.

Comment: As always in questions like these, *read the pre-processor output*. It sounds as if `termios.h` is destroying either `sizeof` or `offsetof`, but why it would do that I have no idea.

Comment: @unwind: Indeed, thanks to your adivce I know now: When termios.h is not included, __builtin_offsetof is used while with termios.h "(((size_t) &((struct Test *)0)->a))" is used. The difference is made in "stddef.h" depending on __compiler_offsetof beeing defined. What I find strange is, that termios.h effects this even when it is included after stddef.h. I can find no reference on __compiler_offsetof or offsetof anywhere but in stddef.h.